# How can I make textarea content possible to styling or set div behaviour like textarea behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a very simple html editor **(not WYSIWYG)** based on jQuery.

My question is how can I make `textarea` or `div` possible to

- write some text on it
- then style i.e tags ( `<strong>some stuff</strong>` change `<strong>` color to blue for example)

I don't ask how to use regular expression and how to manipulate DOM later becouse it's my own problem to solve :D Just how to make "playgroud" for it ;)

When I use textarea it's hmm ( impossible? ) to style stuff inside, but also when I use div... hmm I can just write on div :D So how can I link textarea behaviour on div?

**EDIT** Here is something similar : http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpKEA/) to show how you could do this possibly.

```
$('#edit').keydown(function(){
   var text = $(this).val();

   $('#preview').html(text); 
});
```

this is your html

```
<textarea id="edit">

</textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

and your css

```
#preview{ width:100%; background-color:#eee; padding:20px}

#preview strong{color:blue;}
```